# Ограничение на создание экземпляров класса C++

Tags: классы, c++

Мне требуется, что бы можно было создавать один экземпляр класса, а при попытке создание двух и более экземпляров вываливалась ошибка! Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

формально, Вам нужен [синглтон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), только немного в искаженном виде.

Посмотрите, как его реализовывают и сможете сделать то, что хотите.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте статическую переменную в конструкторе под счётчик

Comment: Тот же Синглтон. Те же раки, только в крапинку :)

Comment: Предположим, один экземпляр создан (static bool alreadyCreated = true
), затем осуществляется попытка создать второй экземпляр, то как в самом классе блокировать эту возможность?

Comment: Допустим, это будет не конструктор, а оператор `new`.

Comment: @mega допустим, как вариант! А как это отвечает на мой вопрос?

Comment: >А как это отвечает на мой вопрос?

 void* MyClass::operator new( size_t size ){
   static bool alreadyCreated = false;
   if( alreadyCreated ){
     return NULL;
   }
   alreadyCreated = true;
   return::operator new( size );
 }
В конструкторе примерно то же самое, только вместо `NULL` бросаем какое-нить исключение:

 MyClass::MyClass( void ){
   static bool alreadyCreated = false;
   if( alreadyCreated ){
     throw "already exists!!!";
   }
   alreadyCreated = true;
   ...
 }

Comment: А как для конечного пользователя сделать процедуру обработки исключительных ситуаций для данного класса "невидимой", то есть что бы не было необходимости включать в код try?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте конструктор приватным, создание экземпляров пусть будет доступно только через фабрику. Отмените конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания, которые есть по умолчанию. Всю логику можно реализовать в фабрике. Следите за вашими потоками -- что будет, если два потока одновременно захотят создать первый экземпляр?

Псевдокод:

```
class Target : Noncopyable // Noncopyable отменяет assignment/copyctor
{
    friend class TargetFactory;
  private:
    Target() {}
};

class TargetFactory
{
    static bool alreadyCreated = false;
    static mutex mutex;
    static Target* Create()
    {
        lock(mutex)
        {
            if (alreadyCreated)
                throw ConstraintViolation();
            alreadyCreated = true;
            return new Target();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Я на данный момент многопоточность не использую, спасибо за пример!

Comment: Если не секрет что такое фабрика ?!

Comment: @rejie: ну, это где-то то, что в моём примере `TargetFactory`: штука, которая создаёт экземпляры другого класса. А вообще, [вот](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [вот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) и [вот](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за подсказку! Из википедии:

> Возможная реализация на C++ (известная как синглтон Майерса), где одиночка представляет собой статический локальный объект. Важным моментом является то, что конструктор класса объявлен как private, что позволяет предотвратить создание экземпляров класса за пределами его реализации. Помимо этого, закрытыми также объявлены конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания. Последние следует определять, так как это позволяет в случае их случайного вызова из кода получить легко обнаруживаемую ошибку компоновки. Отметим также, что приведенный пример не является потокобезопасным в С++03, для работы с классом из нескольких потоков нужно защитить переменную theSingleInstance от одновременного доступа, например, с помощью мьютекса или критической секции. Впрочем, в C++11 синглтон Майерса является потокобезопасным и без всяких блокировок.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае я, наверное, погорячился: если оператор `new` вернет `NULL`, возможно произойдет исключение (хотя и не обязательно, не проверял), а вот второй должен быть рабочим:

```
try{
  MyClass*a = new MyClass;
}
catch( const char*pszMessage ){
  // уже существует
}
```

> А как для конечного пользователя сделать процедуру обработки исключительных ситуаций для данного класса "невидимой", то есть что бы не было необходимости включать в код try?

[[@rejie](/users/263/rejie)](/users/263/rejie), а как Вы собирались контролировать обработку случая, когда производится попытка создать второй экземпляр класса? Думаю, Вам надо сначала подумать над этим вопросом.

Если конечному пользователю нужен указатель на объект, то просто пишем функцию, которая заворачивает создание класса в `try-catch`.

Если конечному пользователю нужен объект "на стеке", то без обработки исключений не обойтись, если только конечный пользователь сам не проверяет счетчик объектов.

**p.s.: комментарии кончились, пришлось выделить ответ.**

Comment: Наверное имеет смысл рассказать зачем это всё мне нужно? не могу определиться куда двигаться дальше! Есть API стороннего производителя в в виде dll написанная на C. Содержит в себе как обычные функции так и функции обратного вызова (API осуществляет взаимодействие с некоторым приложением). Раз я использую C++ логичней было бы инкапсулировать всё это дело в класс.

Comment: Как я понял использовать CallBack Функции внутри класса не получится из за необходимости использовать Extern "C". Придётся вовремя вызова CallBack, из тела CallBack вызывать соответствующую статическую функцию класса, как то кривовато!?

Comment: С одной стороны инициализация API, производится один раз, CallBack функции представлены единичным экземпляром, с другой для получения и обработки данных уместно использовать несколько экземпляров класса. Как то надо всё это соединить в одно целое! Интерфейс к моему классу должен быть минимален, понятен для использования сторонними разработчиками. Как то так...

Comment: В `CallBack'и` обычно позволяют передавать некую переменную `AppUserData`, которую можно использовать под хранение объекта, т.е. к примеру:

 SomeApiCall( ..., Callback, AppUserData );
 ...
 INT CALLBACK Callback( ..., AppUserData ){
   ...
 }
Вот, если в эту `AppUserData` передать в `SomeApiCall` объект, то в самом `CallBack'е` можно передать управление этому объекту:

 MyObject*Obj = new MyObject( ... );
 SomeApiCall( ..., Callback, (...)Obj );
 ...
 INT CALLBACK Callback( ..., AppUserData ){
   return ((MyObject*)AppUserData)->SomeCallback( ... );
 }
т.е. контроль числа объектов не нужен!

Comment: Чтобы настроить CallBack мне необходимо вызвать функцию типа  SET_CALLBACK (CALLBACK pfConnectionStatusCallback, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize) то есть в принципе то о чём вы говорите не реализовать!

Comment: >то есть в принципе то о чём вы говорите не реализовать!
Несколько вариантов:
1. Если какой-то параметр, передаваемый в `SET_CALLBACK` (`pnExtendedErrorCode` или `lpstrErrorMessage`) можно извлечь из `CallBack'а`, то можно сопоставить объект с ним. А в колбеке производить поиск по списку таких сопоставлений, чтобы найти нужный экземпляр класса.
2. Если:
 1) Параметры, передаваемые в `SET_CALLBACK` можно извлечь из `CallBack'а`
 2) параметры, передаваемые в `SET_CALLBACK` можно извлечь по адресу
 3) адрес какого-то параметра не меняется в API
то можно прицепить объект к такому параметру